# preventing yarn from running in wrong directory

Tags: yarn-v2

Sometimes I run yarn (2) in the wrong directory, which can result in the download of thousands of files. Cleaning that up takes a lot of time.

Is there an easy way to prevent yarn from running in a certain directory?

I am using Windows, by the way. But an OS independent solution would be even nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

1. In that directory create a subdirectory `node_modules`.
2. Remove the right to write in that subdirectory for the relevant user(s).

The result looks like this:

```
> yarn add cypress      
yarn add v1.22.15
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
error An unexpected error occurred: 
"EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\\...\\node_modules\\ansi-escapes'".
```

An nothing is downloaded into that `node_modules`.